# `set -e` doesn't abort the script when a sub-shell fails as part of `export`

Tags: bash, subshell, set

When running the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
export X=$(false)
echo That did not abort
X=$(false)
echo That did abort
```

It outputs:

```
That did not abort
```

So `export X=` doesn't abort the execution, but `X=` does.

Why does it not abort on an erroneous `export X=`, even though `set -e` is set?